# Webdriverio V8: How to configure saucelab ansd also how to execute the script using sauce

Tags: javascript, configuration, cucumber, webdriver-io, saucelabs

Webdriverio V8: How to configure saucelab and also how to execute the script using sauce.

I am using JavaScript with BDD cucumber.

I am trying for first time.
Please help me in configuration and execution of the script using sauce